# Android: Release and testing mode?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

I'm working on android project and I want to set some variable on running time, how to do it ?

to be more specific I want to have two running configuration:

1. pre production configuration: where I use an url for testing (exemple String url = staging.domain.net)
2. production configuration: where I use an other url (exemple url = api.domain.net)

I though about using ant but I have no idea how !

**Edit 1:**

My application accesses remote servers and services, using a test URL, sometime I want to use the production URL and not test url. So is possible to have two running configuration setting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define both URLs in your code and decide which one to use depending on `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to define them in your code you can use a property (`setprop prop value`) and then retrieve it in your app (`getprop prop`).

If you are using the emulator there's even a -prop option

```
-prop <name>=<value>           set system property on boot
```

Comment: I opened run configuration -> target -> additional emulator command line options I have add (-prop url="My_url_for_testing") but how to get this value ?

Comment: getprop url from emulator command line should show the value. Use Runtime.exec() in your app.

Comment: sorry I kind begginer on this so is it Like this ? 
            java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop");
            BufferedReader input =
                    new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
           {
                System.out.println("line); //<--
Parse data here.
                
            }
            input.close();

Comment: Yes, but you can get just the property you want: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop url");