# Eclipse Java: Define final variable based on build configuration

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, build-process

I want to have a `final` variable that is `true` when I run the Debug version of my project, and `false` when I run the Run version.  I understand I can do this with build configurations but have no idea how to set this up in Eclipse.  There don't appear to be any tutorials or questions on Stack Exchange regarding defining variables specifically.

I'm compiling Java in Eclipse Classic 4.2, creating an Android app using the ADT plugin.

---

EDIT: Per @Xavi, I set up the following:

```
    try {
        String line = null;
        java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop debugging");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("Property:", line); //<-- Parse data here.
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And in the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field of the Target tab of the Debug Configurations window, I've entered:

```
-prop debugging=true
```

Unfortunately it looks like this only works in emulator mode.  It doesn't print anything when running on my phone.  (It works fine running on an emulator.)

---

EDIT: Per @Sharks I found some links that seem relevant, but I don't know how to apply them to my situation:

- [Android - use ant to create build configurations that change configuration values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032078/android-use-ant-to-create-build-configurations-that-change-configuration-value)
- http://www.bonobolabs.com/fuck-the-android-build-process/

Comment: the quickest solution is to use cmdline arguments.
the quick solution is to use a .config file and read that.
and there's always a reflection-based solution ;)

Comment: @Shark - I googled all three of the things you mentioned, but I didn't see anything I understood or that looked appropriate to specifically Android on Eclipse.  The Android configurations in Eclipse seem to have far fewer features/options than for other "languages."  I editing the question listing some links that seemed relevant, but which I can't make apply to my configuration.

Answer (score 4):

If you're working in Eclipse with ADT then you can check variable `BuildConfig.DEBUG`. It's generated automatically and placed in the `gen/<package>/BuildConfig.java`:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   variable = true;
}
```

Comment: uh, i don't think anything except R.java goes there but I might be wrong.

Comment: This feature appeared not a long time ago. So, not a lot people know about it.

Comment: Sounds great then :) when did it appear?

Comment: I heard that BuildConfig.DEBUG is... buggy. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940 - http://www.digipom.com/be-careful-with-buildconfig-debug/
I tried it earlier with the "Run" button and it still returned `true`.

Comment: It's appeared from ADT 17.0.0 (March 2012). @TheMaster42 Run button does not produce release code. But I'm agree with you the feature sometimes behaves incorrectly (the usual solution is to disable Automatic Build and Run clean).

Comment: @Yury In Eclipse I unchecked `Project->Build Automatically` and then chose `Project->Clean...`, followed by `Project->Build Project`.  This still results in BuildConfig.DEBUG evaluating to true when I run my "Run" build.  (The "Run" button in Eclipse.)

Comment: But it's ok. When you export your signed package this value should disappear. Try to create a simple program that simply produce in Activity value of the DEBUG value. At first, at first run this program  from Run command and then export a signed apk file, install it on your device and check the result.

Comment: What I'd want is 'true' when I do 'Debug as' but 'false' otherwise 'Run as' or apk packaged); is this the *intended* way the constant should get generated? If not, its name is highly misleading.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Yury's answer, you could use `-prop debugging=true` in *Additional Emulator Command Line Options* and check it at runtime by means of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop debugging")`

[image: Screenshot of debug configuration]

Also, you might find the following question useful: [Android: Release and testing mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11661547/851811)

Comment: You don't have this option for Android apps.  Or am I missing something?  Please show a screenshot.

Comment: In Eclipse, clicking on the arrow near the Debug button then choosing "Debug Confugurations..." opens a window that contains only 3 tabs: Android, Target, and Common.  None of these appear to have options related to Environment variables.

Comment: You were both right, the option isn't there. I've edited the answer to provide an alternative.

Comment: Looks like this only works for the emulator, and not on an actual phone.  I've updated the original question with the code I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so since command-line arguments don't really work for you; the Eclipse ones don't work for you so why not try something like this

- put a config file in your APK's assets.
- read the file in a static block before your variable assignment
- assign your debug value accordingly to what you read in the file...

  ```
  private ByteArrayOutputStream getAssetFileAsByteArrayOutputStream(String filename)
  {
  AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();//  OutputStream(helper);
  try
  {
      final InputStream assetFile = assetManager.open(filename, AssetManager.ACCESS_RANDOM);
      byte readBuffer[] = new byte[1024 * 64];    //64kB
      int byteCount;
      while ((byteCount = assetFile.read(readBuffer)) > 0)
          byteStream.write(readBuffer, 0, byteCount);
      byteStream.flush();
      //          copiedFileStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e)
  {
  }
  return byteStream;
  }
  ```

Then before you initialize your final (const) value either put a static block

```
  static 
  {
       //read file
       //get the value you want
  }
  public final static Variable myVar = valFromFile ? "DEBUG" : "NORMAL";
```

or just move the initialization of the finalized variable to the constructor, you can initialize final vars in there.